# Как узнать изменения в строке DataGrid (WPF)?

Tags: c#, datagrid, wpf

Вношу изменения в DataGrid. Обрабатываю событие:

```
private void dataGrid_RowEditEnding(object sender, DataGridRowEditEndingEventArgs e)
{
    DataGrid grid = (DataGrid)sender;
    MessageBox.Show((e.Row.Item as Shelf).Id + " " + (e.Row.Item as Shelf).Name);
}
```

в объекте `DataGridRowEditEndingEventArgs e`, только старое значение, в самом `grid` тоже.

Где искать?

Comment: grid.Items.OfType<Shelf>().FirstOrDefault(shelf=>shelf.Id==((Shelf)e.Row.Item).Id) Так не пробовали?

Comment: А не пробовали заглянуть в `grid` _после_ `CommitEdit`?